# Why is ImageView not resizing after new image is loaded using Glide?

Tags: android, imageview, android-glide

When I try to load new image into ImageView using Glide library, if previous image is small and new image is big, ImageView will keep it's size to match previous (smaller) image.

I've tried Picasso and Glide library, the problem is same.

I expect ImageView size to match the size of the new loaded image.

```
 Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                            .load(user.getImageURL())
                            .thumbnail(Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(R.drawable.loading))
                            .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                                @Override
                                public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                    return false;
                                }

                                @Override
                                public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                    profilePicture.setBackground(null);
                                    return false;
                                }
                            })
                            .into(profilePicture);



 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profilePicture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:background="@drawable/loadingsmaller"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the size of the ImageView to wrap_content?

Comment: Yes I have, same thing happens.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone still looking for solution. [this](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Displaying-Images-with-the-Glide-Library#adjusting-image-size-dynamically) helped me.
My image load chain inside custom ImageView was:

```
GlideApp.with(context)
        .load(viewData.uri)
        .thumbnail(GlideApp.with(context).load(viewData.placeholderRes).centerCrop())
        .error(viewData.placeholderRes)
        .apply(
            RequestOptions().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE)
        )
        .into(this)
```

I created class constant:

```
private val target = object : CustomViewTarget<ImageView, Bitmap>(this) {
    override fun onLoadFailed(errorDrawable: Drawable?) {
    }

    override fun onResourceCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {
    }

    override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
        setImageBitmap(resource)
    }
}
```

And changed chain like this:

```
GlideApp
        .with(context)
        .asBitmap()
        .load(viewData.uri)
        .thumbnail(
            GlideApp
                .with(context)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(viewData.placeholderRes)
                .centerCrop()
        )
        .error(viewData.placeholderRes)
        .apply(
            RequestOptions().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE)
        )
```

From now on my ImageView has correct size always after image loaded.